# extract substring using regex in shell script

Tags: regex, shell, substring

The strings could be of form:

1. com.company.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)
2. $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)
3. com.company.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier).$(someRandomVariable)

I need help in writing regex that extract all the string inside $(..)

I created a regex like `([(])\w+([)])` but when I try to execute in shell script, it gives me error of unmatched parenthesis.

This is what I executed:

```
echo "com.io.$(sdfsdfdsf)"|grep -P '([(])\w+([)])' -o
```

I need to get all matching substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question specifies "shell", but not "bash". So I'll start with a common shell-based tool (awk) rather than assuming you can use any particular set of non-POSIX built-ins.

```
$ cat inp.txt

com.company.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)
$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)
com.company.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier).$(someRandomVariable)

$ awk -F'[()]' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){print $i}}' inp.txt

PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER
PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier
someRandomVariable
```

This awk one-liner defines a field separator that consists of opening or closing brackets. With such a field separator, every even-numbered field will be the content you're looking for, assuming all lines of input are correctly formatted and there are no parentheses embedded inside other parentheses.

If you did want to do this in POSIX shell alone, the following would be an option:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line; do
  while expr "$line" : '.*(' >/dev/null; do
    line="${line#*(}"
    echo "${line%%)*}"
  done
done < inp.txt
```

This steps through each line of input, slicing it up using the parentheses and printing each slice. Note that this uses `expr`, which most likely an external binary, but is at least included in POSIX.1.

Comment: Can we do it w/o input from file? I have a string that I get.

Comment: This worked for me, `echo 'com.company.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier).$(someRandomVariable)' | awk -F'[()]' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){print $i}}'`

Comment: 1 more question - if I have to evaluate the expression $i - how would I do it?

Comment: I'm gonna say .. "probably". :-)  What do you mean by "the expression $i"?  In awk, `$i` means "the field identified by the variable `i`".

Answer (score 2):

Problem is use of double quotes in `echo` command which is interpreting `$(...)` as a [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

You can use single quotes:

```
echo 'com.io.$(sdfsdfdsf)' | grep -oP '[(]\w+[)]'
```

---

Here is an alternative using builtin BASH regex:

```
$> re='[(][^)]+[)]'
$> [[ 'com.io.$(sdfsdfdsf)' =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
(sdfsdfdsf)
```

Comment: Error is gone, but this is nor producing any output. I would have expected sdfsdfdsf as output.

Comment: On my system this gives me `(sdfsdfdsf)` as output

Comment: I may be doing something wrong. I created a .sh file with your ideone code and when I run it, I get `grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]`

Comment: @prabodhprakash: Does your `grep` support `-P` option? It is only supported by gnu grep.

Comment: Try my bash alternative. Make sure you execute it using BASH shell.

Comment: I'm running using /bin/sh - is that the issue?

Comment: Yep, @anubhava is probably using bash

Comment: @prabodhprakash: Yes you will need `/bin/bash` for my BASH alternative code. For `grep -P` you need to be using gnu grep.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it quite simple with sed

```
echo 'com.io.$(asdfasdf)'|sed -e 's/.*(\(.*\))/\1/g'
```

Gives

```
asdfasdf
```

For two fields:

```
echo 'com.io.$(asdfasdf).$(ddddd)'|sed -e 's/.*((.*)).$((.*))/\1 \2/g'
```

Gives

```
asdfasdf ddddd
```

Explanation:

```
sed -e 's/.*(\(.*\))/\1/g'
          \_/\____/  \/
           |    |     |_ print the placeholder content
           |    |___ placeholder selecting the text inside the paratheses
           |____ select the text from beginning including the first paranthese
```

Comment: You have added a \ before $ . I have to do without that \

Comment: use echo 'com.io.$(asdf)'   single qoute will do it. I edited the answer.

Comment: The edited soln works, but for input like `echo 'com.io.$(asdfasdf).$(hello world)'|sed -e 's/.*(\(.*\))/\1/g'` - it prints only `hello world`. Can it be please modified to output all of them.

Comment: echo 'com.io.$(asdfasdf).$(ddddd)'|sed -e 's/.*(\(.*\)).$(\(.*\))/\1 \2/g'  but you have to know how many fields you will get beforehand.

Comment: That is unknown. Essentially, I need to get all matching substrings.

Comment: You have to test it first, then call the respective function.    grep -o '\$' <<< 'com.io.$(asdfasdf).$(ddddd)' | wc -l           this gives you 2

Comment: What are the changes in calling extractor? (I'm sorry for these many questions, but I'm little bad at regex)